# Javascript get url of image clicked

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I've been googling for days now (now at the point of frustration) trying to figure out how to do this. I'm not new to development but I am new to web development specifically and I'm trying to make a browser extension for Firefox.

My issue is that I can't seem to find from googling questions on here and searching through the web API how do it exactly although I got very close.

I want the extension to auto-download an image when clicked. I found this snippet of code from a question on here.

```
var link = document.createElement('a'); // I don't understand the point of this line given what I'm trying to do

link.href = 'images.jpg';
link.download = 'Download.jpg';

// I can work with the two lines above but I don't understand point of the lines below 

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Also after looking at the MDN docs I know that I need to use browser.broswerAction.onClicked but I can't figure out what to put as the listener for what I'm to do (pass a listener that has the info for the particular image clicked) The example on MDN for browserAction.onClicked uses tab as the listener and obviously that wouldn't work me as it would defeat the entire purpose of the functionality I'm trying to achieve.

Response to the comments and answer so far. Thanks for confirming that none of what I found is related to what I'm trying to do. Hence why I got frustrated and made the question.

Note: In case you're wondering why I'm trying to do this. I came up with it as a project to help me brush up on JS. I don't want to do anything else or less because I'm not into web design and I want to do something that can only be done in JS.

**Update** At the risk of getting downvoted for doing this I'm going to do it for the sake of future readers because I know what it's like to google and come across a question on here that was asked years prior but never answered. That is I'm going to reveal that I had a Eureka moment and solved my own question. Here's the code. Also after thinking about what I'm asking it doesn't completely solve it because it doesn't exactly auto-download because it prompts you with the "save file" prompt but I've come to realize that true auto-downloading may not be possible for security reasons. (which I completely understand)

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')
var tag;
for (var counter =0; counter< imgs.length; counter++)
{

    if (imgs[counter].src == '')
        continue;
    tag = document.createElement('a');
    tag.setAttribute('download', counter + '.jpg'); 
    tag.href = imgs[counter].src;
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
    imgs[counter].onclick = function() 
    { 
    tag.click()
    }
}
```

Comment: That snippet looks completely unrelated. It dynamically creates a link to an image, inserts it into the document, then clicks on it.

Comment: The [documentation for `browserAction.onClick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/onClicked) says: "*Fired when a browser action icon is clicked.*" That doesn't look related either.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. "*auto-download an image when clicked*" - OK, but which image? All images on all pages the user visits?

Comment: Yes any image the user clicks on the current page of the current tab. think of doing a google image search and being able to download an image from the results just by single clicking it.